# Как использовать 2 ядра в nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Всем привет.

Есть цикл от -1000 до 1000. Выполняю в одном потоке, и все нормально. Использую модуль cluster, но он запускает просто новые виды экземпляров приложения. Я делю цикл на 2 части: от -1000 до 0 и от 0 до 1000.

Как сделать, чтоб в одном случае запускался первый цикл, в другом - второй? Может, параметры как-то передать?

Comment: что? никто не знает?

Answer (score 2):

Я могу предложить вариант с использованием модуля 'cluster'. Тестировал решение для NodeJS 4.1.2 версии.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    var workers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs && i < 2; i++) {
        workers.push(cluster.fork());
    }

    //set worker technical callbacks
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    });
    cluster.on('online', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.id + ' ready');
    });

    //send messages to workers
    workers[0].send(0);
    workers[1].send(1);

    //set callback for worker responses
    cluster.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log("Master process received message "+msg);
        workers[msg].kill();
    });
}
else {
    //worker logic for messages from master process
    process.on('message', function(msg) {
        if (msg == 0) {console.log("One logic");}
        else if (msg == 1) {console.log("Second logic");}

        console.log("Worker with id=" + cluster.worker.id + " received " + msg);
        process.send(msg);
    });
}
```